# How to login to a website with java script using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I want to login to a website and get the page source code from the website.

The page I want to login is "http://sas.ksa.hs.kr/scmanager/stuweb/index.jsp" and the page I want to get the source code after the login is "http://students.ksa.hs.kr/scmanager/stuweb/sukang/spare.jsp"

I'm very new in developing iOS apps. I couldn't understand any questions about this topic in stackoverflow.

Please help.

Comment: There is an example on YouTube [User login and Register/Sign up example using Swift on iOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xwyhCovrScQ). The guy who uploaded the video also has a blog. Have a look at his examples.

Answer (score 0):

Just use any of traffice analyzers (highly recommended Telerik Fiddler), enabled it during the login process and you'll see all the requests send by your browser. You should reproduce them in your application by constructing the same requests bodies and send them to the same URLs - it's like a browser without displaying any content. Read more about HTTP protocol and you'll have success!
For HTTP in swift you can use NSURLSession or any libraries like Alamofire

Comment: Thanks for answering. Do you know any proper blog or website about HTTP protocol?

Comment: First and second links from there https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20http%20protocol%20works are quite good I think. As it uses Fiddler in description. Just learn the protocol format of data, headers, bodies, all about that. Types of requests, encoding data and other. It's very common information, for example I was studied for that in school. Best regards!